# SEO Ultimate with Wordpress 5.5.3

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting these warning after updating to Wordpress 5.5.3 and PHP v. 7.2/3/4

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". 
Did you mean to use "continue 2"? 
in wp-content/plugins/seo-ultimate/modules/class.su-module.php on line 1195  

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at /wp-content/plugins/seo-ultimate/modules/class.su-module.php:1195) 
in /wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase2.php on line 1338
```

How to fix it is the main question, but temporarily,
How do I suppress it in Wordpress? I have set debug to false in wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in your wp-config to suppress the warning messages-

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', 0 );
```